# Should pandas dataframes be nested?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a python script that drives an old fortran code to locate earthquakes. I want to vary the input parameters to the fortran code in the python script and record the results, as well as the values that produced them, in a dataframe. The results from each run are also convenient to put in a dataframe, leading me to a situation where I have a nested dataframe (IE a dataframe assigned to an element of a data frame). So for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def some_operation(row):
    results = np.random.rand(50, 3) * row['p1'] / row['p2']
    res = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['foo', 'bar', 'rms'])
    return res

# Init master df
df_master = pd.DataFrame(columns=['p1', 'p2', 'results'], index=range(3))
df_master['p1'] = np.random.rand(len(df_master))
df_master['p2'] = np.random.rand(len(df_master))
df_master = df_master.astype(object) # make sure generic types can be used
# loop over each row, call some_operation and store results DataFrame
for ind, row in df_master.iterrows():
    df_master.loc[ind, "results"] = some_operation(row)
```

Which raises this exception:

> ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame

It works as expected, however, if I change the last line to this:

```
df_master["results"][ind] = some_operation(row)
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why does .loc (and .ix) fail when the slice assignment succeeds? If the some_operation function returned a list, dictionary, etc., it seems to work fine.
2. Should the DataFrame be used in this way? I know that dtype object can be ultra slow for sorting and whatnot, but I am really just using the dataframe a convenient container because the column/index notation is quite slick. If DataFrames should not be used in this way is there similar alternative? I was looking at the Panel class but I am not sure if it is the proper solution for my application. I would hate forge ahead and apply the hack shown above to some code and then have it not supported in future releases of pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why does `.loc` (and `.ix`) fail when the slice assignment succeeds? If the some_operation function returned a list, dictionary, etc. it seems to work fine.

This is a strange little corner case of the code. It stems from the fact that if the item being assigned is a DataFrame, `loc` and `ix` assume that you want to fill the given indices with the content of the DataFrame. For example:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[100], 'b':[200]})
>>> df1.loc[[0], ['a', 'b']] = df2
>>> df1
     a    b
0  100  200
1    2    5
2    3    6
```

If this syntax *also* allowed storing a DataFrame as an object, it's not hard to imagine a situation where the user's intent would be ambiguous, and ambiguity does not make a good API.

> 2. Should the DataFrame be used in this way?

As long as you know the performance drawbacks of the method (and it sounds like you do) I think this is a perfectly suitable way to use a DataFrame. For example, I've seen a similar strategy used to store the trained scikit-learn estimators in cross-validation across a large grid of parameters (though I can't recall the exact context of this at the moment...)

Comment: Ok makes sense. I was not aware of the .loc fill behavior you demonstrated. Thanks.